# Serialize nested objects with Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to properly serialize nested objects. For example, let's say I have the following class which describes an object I want to serialize.

```
public class MyObject
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "data")]
    public string Data { get; set; }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public MyObject()
    {
    }

    public MyObject(object obj)
    {
        Data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
        Type = obj.GetType().FullName;
    }
}
```

And in my code if I want to create a new instance of this object, I could do something like this:

```
static MyObject GetMyObject<T>(object goo)
{
    var v = (T)goo;
    MyObject obj = new MyObject();
    obj.Type = goo.GetType().FullName;
    obj.Data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v);
    return obj;
}
```

This all works fine if I've got a single object... but I also need to serialize a List of MyObjects. So, I've got something like this.

```
static MyObject GetMyObjectGroup(MyObjectGroup group)
{
    List<MyObject> children = new List<MyObject>();
    
    //Loop through the list of objects and serialize them
    foreach (var obj in group.Objects)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            continue;
        if (obj.GetType() == typeof(MyObjectGroup))
            return GetMyObjectGroup(obj as MyObjectGroup);
            
        MyObject child = new MyObject();
        child.Type = obj.GetType().FullName;
        child.Data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, GeometryResolver.Settings);
        children.Add(child);
    }

    //Now create a parent obj and set the data to the list of serialized children
    MyObject parent = new MyObject();
    parent.Type = group.GetType().FullName;
    parent.Data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(children);
    return parent;
}
```

Yet, when I try to call the `GetMyObjectGroup` method and look at the results, the json objects don't look correct. It seems to be putting a lot of `\"` characters everywhere in the list of children that get serialized. For example, my Json looks like this:

```
{
    "type": "MyObjectGroup",
    "data": "[{\"type\":\"SomeType\",\"data\":\"{\\\"version\\\":1000}},{\"type\":\"SomeType\",\"data\":\"{\\\"version\\\":2000}}]
}
```

When I think it should be reading like this:

```
{
    "type": "MyObjectGroup",
    "data": [
        {
            "type": "SomeType",
            "data": "{\"version\":1000}"
        },
        {
            "type": "SomeType",
            "data": "{\"version\":2000}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: C# (and JSON) use double quotes as a string delimiter. For example `var hello = "Hello";`. If a string containing an embedded quote, it must be _escaped_ by prefacing it with a backslash (\\). If you look at a string containing quotes in the debugger, it will show the escaped quotes, backslashes and all. When you look at a string like that in the debugger, hover over the variable and click the `View` drop down, choosing the `Text` viewer

Comment: @Flydog57 I know that escape characters are necessary. But, as I said in my post, the serializer is putting an extra escape character inside the list of children that get serialized. My question is how can I avoid that from happening.

Comment: Json you posted  is not valid, it can not be this way

Comment: @Serge Thank you for catching that. I have modified the original JSON.

Comment: What are you eventually trying to achieve? Just so you know, JSON.NET supports `TypeNameHandling` setting, so that type metadata gets included with the object (allowing for concrete type deserialization etc): https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationSettings.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code. Everything is ok for me. You have only one bug. If you want to make your method recursive, you have to move `var children = new List<MyObject>()` and parent code outside of GetMyObjectGroup method.

And you can make your code more simple

```
    children.Add(GetMyObject<object>(obj));

    .... 

    var parent = GetMyObject<List<MyObject>>(children);
```

you can test the result using this code

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parent);

MyObject parent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(json);

List<MyObject> children = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyObject>>(parent.Data);
```

Comment: Thanks @Serge. This does make the recursion work better and the code is much cleaner. I still have a bunch of extra `\"` characters in the list of children serialization... but I think I can handle that in the deserialization process.

Comment: @andyopayne It is called an escape characters, it is normal,   You can use my code to test it.